# Transition to the existing instance of ContentPage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application with `MyWebViewPage : ContentPage`, which set in the App.xaml.cs as MainPage. Every time when I use `await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyWebViewPage())` for transition on the MainPage from other pages in the application, a new instance of type MyWebViewPage has created in memory. Can I realize transition on the existing instance of page MyWebViewPage without creating new instance of this type? I use media player on this page which linked with SignalR and this player plays sounds as many times as instances of this type was created. So I need to have only one instance of this type. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried saving the instance and navigating to the same instance? So instead of doing:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyWebViewPage());
```

You do:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(_webViewPage ??= new MyWebViewPage());
```

Or if you don't like the ternary:

```
if (_webViewPage == null)
    _webViewPage = new MyWebViewPage();

await Navigation.PushAsync(_webViewPage);
```

Comment: Ok, It's almost clear. Should I pass an instance of MyWebViewPage to the page from which I want to make transition?

Comment: I would save it somewhere relevant. If it is a shared resource that is used all across the App. Then, I would consider instantiating it one place where that instance is reachable.

Comment: @andrey.t An example, you could use [NavigationStack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.navigationstack?view=xamarin-forms) to reuse your player page instance or try to use IoC